# Does heap allocation always mean immediate RAM access?

Tags: java, volatile, jit

Assuming Java JIT-compiles code such as building a linked list,
is it possible for `new Link` (and its constructor) to return without accessing RAM at all? In other words, can VM, at least in theory, perform allocation only in the processor cache and only do actual memory allocation when flushing (for example, allocating the whole list or a list segment in one go)?

Aside from being interesting on its own, this came up while I was considering the actual relative penalty of using the `volatile` keyword when paired with new object creation. Assume a mutable list defined like this:

```
class Link<E> {
    final E elem;
    Link<E> next = null
    Link(E e, Link<E> tail) {
        elem = e;
        next = tail;
    }

    public void append(E e) {
        next = new Link(e, null);
    }
}
```

Can adding a `volatile` keyword to field `next` impact the performance of repeated calls to `append` (possibly shortly followed by dereferencing the whole collection, freeing the memory for garbage collection), limiting optimisations that JVM is able to do with the code in a significant way (at least in theory)?

Comment: "perform allocation only in the processor cache" - no, I do not think so. I am a bit confused by your point about `volatile` - if you need proper semantics, you _need_ to use it, performance is irrelevant in this case, compared to correctness.

Comment: If there is sufficient CPU cache, operations can be done fully in CPU cache because they are coherent on all modern processors. The cost of volatile is not because flushing to memory (which doesn't happen). The cost is in the form of reduced compiler optimization and the execution of fences that prevent reordering within the CPU.

Comment: For example; if a volatile store is followed by a volatile load to a different address, they need to be performed in order because this is typically something a CPU would like to optimize (look for store buffers) On certain platforms (ARM/X86)  it will cause delay of the load from cache till the store is committed to the cache . And this is typically what makes a volatile expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I am only aware of the semantics of executions fences, not the itty-gritty details, so I guess I need to read up on that. Does this mean that *compiled* volatile fields, if a part of a structure whose usage otherwise warrants its placement in the CPU cache, can have a performance cost significantly slower than direct RAM access? It seems my understanding was decades stale.

Comment: You can't control if you write something to DRAM or cache. You just write it to 'memory'. Caching is completely transparent for typical usages.

Comment: In your example I would be more worried about the litter you are creating than the overhead of volatile.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I am interested in the typical end result (lets forget Java for a moment and step down to native code to remove a layer). When I was tought, `volatile` was explained to me as a RAM vs register thing  (SMP was completely new and I don't think execution fences were even a thing). This granted certain intuition about its execution cost. Now I see it is not well founded, and perhaps even completely wrong.

Comment: Modern processors are all load/store architectures. Meaning that most operations like ALU operations can't directly access memory and always need to go through a register. Even the X86 which is a memory/register architecture, once translated to uops is a load/store architecture. So volatile can't prevent making use of a register; the key difference is that volatile controls how long it is going to remain in a register or if it needs to be written to cache. This a compiler concern.

Comment: Accessing cache is quite cheap if the cache-line is in the right state on the CPU that does the access. There is no need to access main memory at all. The primary price to pay is to restrict the reorderings in either the CPU or compiler. And of course; if the cacheline isn't in the right state in the cache, then the price will be high.

Comment: Thank you, your comments were very informative. I still do not have a clear view of the subject (i.e., creating a modestly sized temporary linked list) - apart from my synchronisation, JVM needs to maintain its own while maintaining the heap - but now I am armed with good clues on what to google.

Comment: A lot of information you will find about this topic is unclear at best or completely wrong at worst (e.g. the flushing to memory fallacy). And as a consequence performance+JMM is difficult to get started with. In your case I would focus on making the code correct first. Also I would think twice about dealing with concurrency at all. Sprinkling code with volatiles and synchronized blocks is just a recipe for problems.

Comment: Also the JMM is set up in such a way that you can create your linked list in 1 thread and use it in another. There is no need for any synchronization logic is the list isn't modified after it is created as long as you find a save exchange mechanism like placing it in a volatile/atomicreference/queue for example.

Answer (score 2):

> Can adding a volatile keyword to field next impact the performance of repeated calls to append (possibly shortly followed by dereferencing the whole collection, freeing the memory for garbage collection), limiting optimisations that JVM is able to do with the code in a significant way (at least in theory)?

The answer is, of course, yes. The JVM is an abstracted concept. Generalized statements about the performance of some java code only fall in these buckets:

- The Java Memory Model guarantees that this works fine (but that's always about whether something is buggy (sometimes buggy in a way that no existing VM can reproduce, but buggy nonetheless, in that some future version may break your code and it'd be your fault)) - this isn't about performance characteristics, though.
- A statement like: For all major platforms and all major VM releases, at their current versions, this code will perform well. This does not include guarantees about what will happen with the next release or if java runs on a new platform. Also, actually putting this together is incredibly difficult: You either need to be a walking dictionary that knows all the details about all the major VM implementations, or you need to do the work and have about 15 JVMs installed on each of about 3 OSes, on 30 different kinds of hardware platforms, for a total of over a 1000 combinations, that you'd need to performance test before making such statements.

So, given that the above is borderline insanity, the answer to your question is 'Yes'.

Mostly because that's the answer to any question of the form:

> Can (anything) impact the performance of (anything) by limiting optimizations that a JVM is able to do in a significant way at least in theory?

Is 'Yes'.

Some specific knowledge that could be useful:

- A JVM is *usually* capable of (nearly) eliminating the performance impact of a `volatile` keyword if the keyword isn't doing anything useful (e.g. that field is only being read/written to be a single thread or the multi-thread accesses are spaced far apart in time).
- Generally you don't add `volatile` for funsies. You have a need for the threading behaviour, so you can't just compare performance of having the keyword vs. not having the keyword - not having the keyword means the code is broken, so that's obviously a useless and unfair comparison. Instead you need to compare against the next best alternative, such as using an AtomicX or rewriting the code to move the sync-up between threads up.

Comment: This was just a minimalized example needed to state the question. The real problems are of the type 'if I can add some optimisation (sharing of data between several instances, or an internal cache in a large object, at the cost of thread synchronisation (i.e., a volatile check), when it could have an adverse effect. Say adding an O(1) 'focus' with the recently read node bypassing O(log(n)) bintree lookup, but there is a good chance most of the tree may be in the CPU cache. As you said, profiling is very costly and some initial intuition is very helpful.

Comment: Also, the use of the word of 'significant' limited my interest to clear-cut cases of 'yes, quite possible'.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, can VM, at least in theory, perform allocation only in
> the processor cache and only do actual memory allocation when
> flushing...

Real machines don't generally have this ability. A memory word has "an address" (let's ignore any MMU for this discussion), and this address identifies the word whether it's in CPU cache or the real memory.  That the OS knows an address means that it has in some sense "allocated memory". The CPU writes to memory. The hardware might store that in cache and/or memory, now or later, depending on implementation.

It is not usual to have "do not write back from cache" instructions (outside of processor initialization). Thus the CPU does not have a means to prevent the change from showing up in memory. It usually does have a means to force the change to memory; 'volatile' tells the compiler this is wanted.

The JVM, of course, is a virtual machine, so it can do what it wants.  But I'd be quite surprised if there was a 'virtual cache' distinct from the real CPU cache.

One further note - operating systems usually have a mechanism for allocating demand-zero pages, so although the virtual memory exists, it is not necessarily backed by page frames until it is touched, i.e. "RAM" has not been "accessed". A large heap object could conceivably be created partially in this state.  However, this is nothing to do with CPU caches.

As a long-practicing programmer, I find it generally not useful to think about "RAM", but instead think about "address space" and (virtual) "memory".

Comment: "It usually does have a means to force the change to memory; 'volatile' tells the compiler this is wanted." Please define what you mean with 'memory' because if you are referring to main memory than this is incorrect:  modern processors have coherent caches so they do not need to communicate with main memory.

Comment: Perhaps there is a shortage of cache or perhaps there is a limitation in the cache coherence algorithm (e.g. MESI whereby a dirty cache line can't be shared without pushing the cacheline to DRAM; MOESI doesn't have this problem) that forces the cache line to be written.

Comment: It seems I phrased myself wrong; I did not wonder about the ability of JVM - or a native compiler for that matter - to do things explicitly in the CPU cache, but that the overall effect is such in practice. In particular, the effect on the cache and execution of any synchronisation JVM does as part of heap allocation.